# Android MediaPlayer: Error (1,-1004)

Tags: mediaplayer, android

Привет.

Во время проигрывания видео через url в разное время на разных роликах может выскакивать (а может и нет, но в большинстве своем выскакивает) ошибка **MediaPlayer: Error (1,-1004)**

Вычитывал, что данная ошибка скорее всего связана с прерываниеми на http сервере.
Искал упорно, но так и не нашел документацию чтоб точно убедиться.

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, где можно подробнее вычитать об этой ошибке или как посоветуете с не бороться? Может в заголовках сервера что-то не то?

Тестирую на реальных устройствах.

**UPDATE:** Тему можно закрыть. Перевел все на RTSP пока не жаловались и дай Бог не будут :) В любом случае другого выхода не вижу.

**UPDATE 2:** RTSP не на всех Андроид устройствах поддерживается. :(

Comment: поток буфиризировать неплохо было бы

Comment: Так он буферизируется. Ну т.е загружается, можно перематывать. Или Вы как-то иначе имели ввиду?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут ([Android MediaPlayer error - 1004](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211566/android-mediaplayer-error-1004-error-io)) говорят, что это ([Implementing a simple HTTP Server in Java to handle GET methods](http://www.prasannatech.net/2008/10/simple-http-server-java.html)) помогает.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я это видел, но я не могу менять сервер, там nginx :) Может что-то поменять в конфиге? Но менять сервер не могу. Не мой :)

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю какая у Вас стоит задача, но воспроизведение через URL по моему ИМХО - дело плохое и вот почему:

- Разорвется соединение - не сможете воспроизвести файл
- Много трафика, который кушается не единожды, а постоянно. Накладно.
- Не гибко, в регионах с частым инетом не очень

Попробуйте исправить и эту ошибку и архитектурную. Скачивайте файл на карту, ложите в директорию cache и воспроизводите в дальнейшем уже скачанный файл.

Ну это конечно все верно если файлов немного или они небольшого размера. Но вцелом как-то так.

Comment: Спасибо за советы. Все 3 пункта это вопрос о целесообразности и каждый сам решает для себя. Меня все 3 пункта устраивают.

Comment: @DroidAlex, а если это поток радио?

Comment: Поток радио - это совсем другое дело. Это непреревный набор данных, а не файлы. Поэтому все эти пункты там неприменимы. Кроме того там есть специальный протокол - RTMP

Comment: Android RTSP поддерживает а RTMP насколько я знаю нет. В любом случае переписываю все на RTSP, т.к судя по последним проведенным тестам там не прерывается.